# MySQL select query based on array value

Tags: mysql

I have a dynamic array. For example  like this.

```
$color = array('red','blue','green');
"SELECT * FROM mytable where colors=(red or blue or green)"
```

But my array is dynamic. So I don't know the values and how can I loop the array and select the rows.

Comment: use a loop and iterate over the array and fetch results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Comment: Use `IN` in mysql, add the number of placeholders you need and bind the variables. **Edit:** Exactly like in the question @Chris mentions...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php

 $color = array('red','blue','green');


 $ss = 'SELECT * FROM mytable where colors IN ("' . implode('", "', $color ) . '")';

output :

SELECT * FROM mytable where colors IN ("red", "blue", "green")

?>
```

Comment: Not sure this would work jothi since the in () expects string values to be wrapped in single quotes.

Comment: if i select red, it is selecting the rows whose color=red but if i select red and blue, it is returning empty result.. i need something like "SELECT * FROM mytable where colors = RED OR BLUE  OR GREEN

Comment: IN method working  fine for what you expected result .i think something missing in your array @athi

Comment: try to echo   $ss  the query and know that query building working fine or not @athi

Answer (score 0):

use `where in`.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE  COLUMN IN $your_dynamic_array
```